# Pressing the escape key twice clears form fields

Tags: javascript

There is a problem in my JSP page

When user is filling out form fields and presses the escape key twice IE8 automatically clears all he text fields of page. Is there any solution to this issue?

or a way to disable this at all?

I used following code to disable 'Esc' key but issue not resolved, code is not working

```
 if (key == 27) {
 cancelKey(event); 
 return false;}

 function cancelKey(evt) { 
    if (evt.preventDefault) { 
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
    } 
    else { 
    evt.keyCode = 0; 
    evt.returnValue = false; 
    } 
    }
```

any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: tried global `event` instead for IE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

(function() /* Prevent Esc deleting imput and if input is readonly, stop backspace acting as 'Back' */
{
  var inps = document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' ), /* Place BELOW all <input>s */
      field;

  function ih( obj, evt, func )
  { 
    obj.attachEvent ? obj.attachEvent( 'on' + evt, func ) : obj.addEventListener( evt, func, false );
  }      

  function k( e )
  {  
    var evt = ( e || window.event ),
        elem = evt.srcElement || evt.target,
        ro = elem.getAttribute('readonly');

    if( evt.keyCode == 27 || ( ro && evt.keyCode == 8 ) )
      evt.preventDefault ? evt.preventDefault() : evt.returnValue = false;  
  };

  for( var i = 0; ( field = inps[ i ] ); i++ ) 
    ih( field, 'keydown', k );          
})()

</script>
```

It may work or may not. Lot of things [hot keys] can't be prevented.
Source: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?217535-esc-key-clears-html-input-text-values

Comment: Did you write the code yourself? Please provide a reference if not!

Comment: I was editing my post, and in the mean time you just commented :)

Comment: how to use this function? do I need to mention it somewhere? as it has no name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function () {
     if (window.event.keyCode == 27) {
           window.event.returnValue = false;
      }
});
```